# I need to develop a Calculator type Program in Console Application in C sharp

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C sharp Programming and i'm stuck with a program to develop a Calculator like functionality in which it will take the user's input into a int data type called choice and it will read both the operands from user to calculate upon then a switch loop will be executed which on depending on the choice selected perform the desired operation and will give the Output Result.After showing result and breaking the case,the program will ask the user whether to Continue or not and the feedback will be stored on a character variable which will be compared and if selected Y it will redirect the program's execution to the start label.
Below is the Code for the Same:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int choice,op1,op2;
    char ch;
    start:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter First Operand");
    op1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Operand");
    op2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Input \n1. For Addition \n2.For Subtraction \n3.For Multiplication \n4.For Division");
    choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine(op1+op2);

            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine(op1 - op2);
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine(op1*op2);
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine(op1/op2);
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid Choice");
            break;
    }
    end:
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Continue(Y/N)?");
    ch=Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
    if (ch == 'Y')
    {
        goto start;
    }
    else if (ch == 'N')
    {
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Valid Choice");
        goto end;
    }   
}
```

But When I run the code it outputs as desired for the first time but when i select 'Y' it shows the error "exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll".Please Suggest me Some Correction

Comment: I think after entering Y the ´goto.start;´ jumps to the top and ´Console.ReadLine()´ reads the Y (is still in the current line) after pressing enter and tries to convert it to a number. There is probably where the exception happens (would be nice to have the full stack trace).

Comment: I would suggest to debug your application to see where you're getting the error. Your FormatException will be occurring where it's trying to call `Convert.ToInt32()` passing the `Console.ReadLine()` as an argument

Comment: @GeoffJames Exactly it Does Happens !

Comment: From my understanding - an "operand" is `+`, `-` `%`, `*` etc. You can't convert one of these characters to an `int`?

Comment: @GeoffJames These are the operators not operands.operands are the values to be executed operation upon

Comment: Ah that's fair enough. See @Kell's answer below - that should cover the issue with converting the input operator, in that case :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `ch=Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());`

with `ch = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;`

Though if I was to be a purist I'd have to say lose the labels and use a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code.
After below line

```
ch=Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
```

just add the following line because Console.Read() read single Character extra Enter is in buffer. so to clear the buffer after read() just add the below line.

```
Console.ReadLine();
```